# The group is not simple

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I want to show that if $|G|=pqr$ where $p,g,r$ are primes, then $G$ is not simple.

We have that a group is simple if it doesn't have any non-trivial normal subgroups, right?

$$$$

I have done the following:

There are $p$-Sylow, $q$-Sylow and $r$-Sylow in $G$.

$$P\in \text{Syl}_p(G), \ |P|=p, \\ Q\in \text{Syl}_q(G), \ |Q|=q, \\ R\in \text{Syl}_r(G), \ |R|=r$$

$|\text{Syl}_p(G)|=1+kp \mid |G|=pqr$ so $1+kp\mid pqr \Rightarrow 1+kp\mid qr$.

So, $$1+kp=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 
q \\ 
r \\ 
qr 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Similarily, $|\text{Syl}_q(G)|=1+kq \mid |G|=pqr$ so $1+kq\mid pqr \Rightarrow 1+kq\mid pr$.

So, $$1+kq=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 
p \\ 
r \\ 
pr 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

And, $|\text{Syl}_r(G)|=1+kr \mid |G|=pqr$ so $1+kr\mid pqr \Rightarrow 1+kr\mid pq$.

So, $$1+kr=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 
p \\ 
q \\ 
pq 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Is this correct?

Suppose that $|\text{Syl}_p(G)|=1$ or $|\text{Syl}_q(G)|=1$ or $|\text{Syl}_r(G)|=1$. That means that there is one Sylow subgroup that has order $p$, $q$, $r$, respectively, right? Is this Sylow subgroup normal?

Suppose that $|\text{Syl}_p(G)|=q$. That means that the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups is $q$, each of which has order $p$, right? How can we check if these subgroups are normal?

Comment: In all the three options it can be the number of Sylow subgroups is the product of the two primes there.

Comment: I edited it now... Do you mean that it should be so? @Joanpemo

Comment: What if p,q,r = 2,3,5.  The order of your group is 30.  The smallest simple group -- A5 -- It is order 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the three primes are different (otherwise you can try to show separatedly), say $\;p<q<r\;$ . Assume $\;1<n_r\;$ , then $\;n_r=pq\;$ , otherwise $\;n_r=p\;$ or $\;n_r=q\;$, which cannot be as also $\;n_r=1\pmod r\;$ and $\;r>q>p\;$ .

Thus, we already have $\;pq(r-1)=pqr-pq\;$ elements of order $\;r\;$ in the group. If we assume that also $\;n_q>1\;$ , then since there are $\;n_q>q>p\;$ Sylow $\;q-$ subgroups, we have at least $\;p(q-1)=pq-p\;$ elements of order $\;q\;$ .

Toghether, we have at least $\;pqr-pq+pq-p=pqr-p\;$ elements of order $\;r\;$ or $\;q\;$ , leaving only $\;p\;$ elements which *must* be a unique Sylow $\;p$ - subgroup which is then normal.

Comment: What happens when $n_r=1$ ? When we have one Sylow subgroup of order $r$, is it then normal? $$$$ 
When $n_r=pq$, why do we have $pq(r-1)$ elements of order $r$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course. This follows from one of Sylow's theorem: a Sylow subgroup is normal iff it is unique. Since Sylow $\;r-$ subgroups are cyclic of order the prime $\;r\;$ , each such subgroup has $\;r-1\;$ nontrivial elements each of order $\;r\;$  and the intersection of two different Sylow $\;r- $ subgroups is trivial, Thus, in $\;pq\;$ such subgroups we have $\;pq(r-1)\;$ different elements each of order $\;r\;$ .

Comment: Are all Sylow subgroups cyclic?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, in THIS case they are. A group of order a prime is always cyclic.

Comment: In any cyclic group of order $n$, all elements, besides the neutral one, has order $n$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar No, of course not. Only if $\;n\;$ is prime. I think you should know these things BEFORE attempting to tackle exercises about Sylow theorems, with all due respect.

Comment: Yes, I meant a prime number... This holds because of the Lagrange's theorem, or not? The divisors of a prime number $n$ are $n$ and $1$, so all elements, besides the neutral one that has order $1$, must have order $n$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that's right.

Comment: Why is the intersection of two different $r$-Sylow subgroups trivial?

Comment: Shouldn't the second and at the last part be as follows? $$$$ "If we assume that also $\;n_q>1\;$ , then since there are $\;n_q>q>p\;$ Sylow $\;q-$ subgroups, we have **more than** $\;p(q-1)=pq-p\;$ elements of order $\;q\;$ .

Toghether, we have **more than** $\;pqr-pq+pq-p=pqr-p\;$ elements of order $\;r\;$ or $\;q\;$ ," $$$$ Since **at least** would mean that it can take that value, or not?

Comment: No, I think it is "at least", I can't see how can we be sure that "more than".

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!! :-)